# How do i efficiently detect if users of an App are nearby to one another in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

For example:say i have stackOverflow iOS app installed on my iphone and am at any random location. I have a question in mind i wanna ask but i want to ask other people who also have stackOverflow app installed on their iphones who are nearby to my current location (--some threshold in feet) . How can i send those nearby users who may or may not have the stackOverflow app running in foreground , a push notification so they can decide if they want to answer my question. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Using GPS to update user location every X minutes does not seem efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to have the user's app periodically update a back-end service with it's coordinates and zip code, (the zip code can be obtained using Google location services), and have the service respond with all users currently within the zip code and their coordinates.

Then the app could determine distance between its coordinates and each of those users' coordinates.

The problem here would be that two users could be very close in location but near the boundaries of adjacent zip codes, and that wouldn't register. But if you can accept that limitation this method would be less prosessing-intensive than having the back-end check the distance to each other user every time a user updated their location.